# How many different committees of 5 can be formed from 8 men and 7 women such that there are at least 2 women in the committee

Tags: combinations

How many different committees of 5 can be formed from 8 men and 7 women so as to include at least 2 women?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of committees of $5$ where at least $2$ women are included

$$\sum_{x=2}^{5}{7 \choose x}\cdot{8 \choose 5-x}$$

Comment: This might not be the answer OP needs, but it is the answer he deserves.